# Issues with the usage of associative containers with a customized comparison type

Tags: c++, stl

Here is an example:

```
std::set<std::string, SpecialCompareLess> setSpecial;
```

I remember when we define an associative container with a customized comparison type, we need to pay attention to some potential issues. But I forget what the issues are.

something like: if you use STL algorithm on the associative container, you have to provide such a specialized comparer rather than let the algorithm picks the default comparer. Otherwise, you will not get the correct results.

If someone knows what I am talking about, can you reminder me what the concern is?

Thank you

Comment: You should probably look at Scott Meyer's "Effective STL" book; it covers such issues, but I don't recall exactly what it says about this one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of such issues, and a lot of them hard to summarise, so there  is no such   a common reference for them. But from my own experience I can tell you several the most frequent and useful:
 1. As you know a comparison function may be any callable type (functor,lambda,function reference etc.). But always use functors or lambdas because compiler always inlines them and so you get better performance.
 2. Don't forget to declare parameters of your comparator as const references.
 3. If you can always write apaptors to encapsulate your comaprator large code
 4. Try to write your comparators like pure functions in FP.
 5. If your container consists of pointers you MUST write your own comparator because default comparator will sort pointer values not dereferencing them.
 6. Remember the mathematical difference between equality and equivalence in order to write correct comparator return type (for instance false for equality).
Also several such advices you can find in books of Musser, Meyers and Herb Sutter.